# Exponent and abelian groups

Tags: group-theory

What exponent $e$ can guarantee the group to be abelian? Are there any known results except the case $e = 2$? Thanks for help.

Comment: It is non-true except for $e=1,2$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. If you consider the Heisenberg group $H(p)$ for an odd prime $p$, then $H(p)$ is a non-abelian group of order $p^3$ with exponent $p$.

EDIT: For $4$ consider the quaternions.

Comment: What about non-prime exponents?

Comment: Say you claim $6$ works, well $6$ still annihilates $H(3)$.

Comment: @ksj03: For non-prime exponents consider direct products of groups with prime(-power) exponents.

Comment: ...and to find a non-abelian group of exponent $p^n$, $n\neq 1$, take $H(p)\times C_{p^n}$...

Comment: (Also, $H(2)$ is the Quaternions.)